# KineticJs Canvas with Image Upload

Tags: javascript, image, upload, kineticjs

I want to be able to upload images onto this canvas from the persons computer just for the time being while they use the canvas. I also want it to be moveable and resizeable like the other 2 images I have setup right now. Can someone help create a code that goes along with what I currently have. This is everything I have for it so far so if you could name such with the right class/ids that the parts of mine have. Thank you

```
    <style>
  canvas:active{
  cursor:pointer;
  }
.bg1{
  background-image:url('http://s23.postimg.org/bxtmsd2tn/boutiquebase.jpg');
  }
  .bg2{
  background-image:url('http://s4.postimg.org/bnevxi1y5/wall8.png');
  }

   .bg3{
  background-image:url('http://s13.postimg.org/6cgbaoblh/wall9.png');
  }
</style>

    <div id="container" class="bg1"></div>


  <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/bxtmsd2tn/boutiquebase.jpg" width="50px" id="wall1">
            <img src="http://s4.postimg.org/bnevxi1y5/wall8.png" width="50px" id="wall2">
  <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/6cgbaoblh/wall9.png" width="50px" id="wall3">

<table><tr>
  <td>
    <center> <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/yn6t21ah3/sidetable.png" id="shower" width="100px" style="cursor:pointer;">
   <br>
      <span id="hider1" class="sendingBut" style="cursor:pointer;">Remove </span>

      </center></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
         $('#wall2').click(function() {
    $('#container').removeClass('bg3').removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');
});    

            $('#wall1').click(function() {
    $('#container').removeClass('bg3').removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg1');
});   

            $('#wall3').click(function() {
    $('#container').removeClass('bg1').removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg3');
});   
              </script>
<script>

  function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.find('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.find('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.find('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.find('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.find('.image')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.x();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.y();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.name()) {
          case 'topLeft':
            topRight.y(anchorY);
            bottomLeft.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'topRight':
            topLeft.y(anchorY);
            bottomRight.x(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'bottomRight':
            bottomLeft.y(anchorY);
            topRight.x(anchorX); 
            break;
          case 'bottomLeft':
            bottomRight.y(anchorY);
            topLeft.x(anchorX); 
            break;
        }

        image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

        var width = topRight.x() - topLeft.x();
        var height = bottomLeft.y() - topLeft.y();
        if(width && height) {
          image.setSize({width:width, height: height});
        }
      }
      function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: '#666',
          fill: '#ddd',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          radius: 8,
          name: name,
          draggable: true,
          dragOnTop: false,
  opacity: .01
        });

    anchor.on('mouseout', function () {
        this.opacity(.01);
        layer.draw()
    });
    anchor.on('mouseenter', function () {
        this.opacity(1.00);
        layer.draw()
    });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
          update(this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
          group.setDraggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
          group.setDraggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          this.setStrokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
          this.strokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
      }
      function loadImages(sources, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;
        for(var src in sources) {
          numImages++;
        }



        for(var src in sources) {
          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = sources[src];
        }
      }
      function initStage(images) {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: 'container',
          width: 1000,
          height: 764
        });

    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();


        var furniGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 270,
          y: 100,
          draggable: true
        });
        var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
          x: 100,
          y: 110,
          draggable: true
        });



        /*
         * go ahead and add the groups
         * to the layer and the layer to the
         * stage so that the groups have knowledge
         * of its layer and stage
         */

        layer.add(furniGroup);
        layer.add(yodaGroup);
        stage.add(layer);




   document.getElementById('shower').addEventListener('click', function() {
         furniImg.show();
layer.draw();
           }, false);


   document.getElementById('hider1').addEventListener('click', function() {
         furniImg.hide();
layer.draw();
           }, false);


        var furniImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
  width: 338,
          height: 285,
          image: images.furni,
                    name: 'image'
        });

        furniGroup.add(furniImg);
   addAnchor(furniGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(furniGroup, 338, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(furniGroup, 338, 285, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(furniGroup, 0, 285, 'bottomLeft');

        furniGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });

        var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: images.yoda,
          width: 422,
          height: 243,
          name: 'image'
        });

        yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 422, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 422, 243, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 243, 'bottomLeft');

        yodaGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
        });

        stage.draw();
      }



      var sources = {
        furni: 'http://s29.postimg.org/yn6t21ah3/sidetable.png',
        yoda: 'http://s28.postimg.org/58nni8dzh/blackf10.png'
      };
      loadImages(sources, initStage);





    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code lets you drag an image from the users desktop onto the Kinetic container div.

A new Kinetic.Image will be created from the dropped image.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/w9onv0nm/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);


    // drag image to the div with id='container'
    var container=document.getElementById("container");
    container.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    container.addEventListener("drop", function(e){
      var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (files.length>0) {
          var file=files[0];
          if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined" && file.type.indexOf("image") != -1) {
            var reader=new FileReader();
            reader.onload=function (e) {
                var dragImage=new Image();
                dragImage.onload=function(){
                    newDraggedImage(dragImage);
                };
                dragImage.src=e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);


    // create a new Kinetic.Image from the dropped image
    function newDraggedImage(img){
        layer.add(new Kinetic.Image({
            image:img,
            draggable:true,
        }));
        layer.draw();
    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Drag an image onto the container to create a Kinetic.Image</h4>
    <div id="container"></div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

**[ Addition - creating group & anchors for dropped images ]**

*Warning! This is untested code...tweaking is probably required!*

```
function createGroup(groupId,img,x,y){

    var group = new Kinetic.Group({
      id:groupId,
      x:x,
      y:y,
      draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(group);

    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image:img,
      width:img.width,
      height:img.height,
      name: 'image'
    });
    group.add(image);

    addAnchor(group, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
    addAnchor(group, img.width, 0, 'topRight');
    addAnchor(group, img.width, img.height, 'bottomRight');
    addAnchor(group, 0, img.height, 'bottomLeft');

    group.on('dragstart', function() {
      this.moveToTop();
    });

    return(group);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much although is there a way to add the anchors to it too as well as remove the image? Not to make you code it all but how would i refer to the layer for that image and others that they drag over? Like how I have this to add the anchors i refer to the furnigroup layer
    
    furniGroup.add(furniImg);
   addAnchor(furniGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(furniGroup, 338, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(furniGroup, 338, 285, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(furniGroup, 0, 285, 'bottomLeft');

Comment: and then this to show/hide i refer to the furniimg... but instead id need to add a close button near the image to remove it but basically similar to this code

document.getElementById('shower').addEventListener('click', function() {
         furniImg.show();
layer.draw();
           }, false);

  
   document.getElementById('hider1').addEventListener('click', function() {
         furniImg.hide();
layer.draw();
           }, false);

Comment: Adding anchors & a remove-button is a bit beyond the scope of your question.  Even so, I've added a mockup of how you might code a group+image+anchors--totally untested!  I've added an `id` property to the group so that you can fetch groups by id--much more flexible: `stage:find("#yodoGroup")`. IMHO, this resizing method is substandard in 2 ways: (1) images should be resized proportionally--not be allowed to distort by width or height, (2) Adding anchors to all images is a resource hog--instead refactor to make 1 set of anchors that can be attached to any image. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Well after over an hour trying to work it around still can't seem to get this to work. Is there a way to basically set it so that there is basically an "Img" and "Group" I can create like I have for the others and us to reference? Basically unique names that I can recognize or know what parts to reference because I tried and it seems to get mixed up when everything is called group and image. I even tried adding a name to the original part that creates a new kinetic image and such. Sorry for being such a pain with this, i just can't seem to get any anchors to work no matter what I try.

Comment: Here's an example of a reusable anchor that can be temporarily assigned to resize any image.  The image is always resized proportionally so it never becomes distorted vertically or horizontally.  Usage: Just click on any image and the anchor will be "temporarily assigned" to that image and can resize that assigned image. No anchor group is needed because the anchor "attaches" to any selected image. If you need anchors on all 4 corners of an image you can use my BottomRight-Anchor code as a starting point to code the other 3 anchors yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/kwLqj6ff/ Cheers!

Comment: Alright so I created a jsfiddle then edited the code for the images that are dragged over from the computer, they now have a layer called "newpic" I managed to make a show/hide option but it effects all images dragged in(is there a way to set it differently for each image? Also I tried to work with the jsfiddle you gave for the one anchor resizing but couldnt get it to work for this and tried to work with the one i had... it basically shows the anchors but theyre under the image and dont do anything they also wont move with the image.

Comment: I know this is more than originally asked but since you already saw most my code maybe you could help with something for this http://jsfiddle.net/dsj00qoy/2/

Comment: Here's example code that combines drag-to-stage with a reusable-resizer:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4bawqg3f/ Good luck with your project!

Comment: I swear this is my last question because I have everything sorted except this one thing. When I have more than one picture and click on the close button I added it removes them all including uploaded images and ones already in the canvas. How can I set it to only effect the right image? Note images already added in like the table which is labeled ta3group http://jsfiddle.net/dsj00qoy/10/

Comment: Well, `BR.img` holds a reference to the one image that BR is currently assigned to.  So in your closebutton click handler you could use `BR.img` to close the desired image. ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help on these issues even though it was more than i originally asked. I really appreciate it and think I'm getting to understand how to use kineticjs better too :)